# Is the following statement in group theory true?

Tags: group-theory, projection, direct-product

Let $G$ be a group such that

$$G=\prod G_i,$$

where above product is arbitrary. Suppose that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that

$$\prod G_i=H\prod G_i',$$

where $G_i'$ is derived subgroup of $G_i$.
Let $p_i$ be the projection map from $G$ to $G_i$ for each $i$. Let $H_i$ be the mapping of $H$ under $p_i$. Suppose  we know that $$H_i=G_i$$ for each $i$. Then is it true that $$G=H?$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I changed "can we say that" to "is it true that". I am afraid that I find "can we say that" irritating, because obviously we can say it! The question is would it be correct.

Comment: I don't believe that the map $p_i$ is well defined in general, so it is not clear that the question makes sense.

Comment: Is it intended that the product is a direct product? Anyway, even then, certainly not. Take $G = A_5 \times A_5$ and let $H$ be the diagonal subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm guessing that when the OP says "above product is arbitrary" they mean that it's a direct product, but of a possibly infinite class of groups, rather than that it's a (not necessarily direct) product. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446287/can-we-write-a-subgroup-as-a-product-of-subgroups). As stated the question does not make sense or is missing context or definitions. In the case where $G_i = G_i'$ for all $i$ the condition is satisfied for any subgroup $H$.